# Different options for multiple glossaries

Tags: glossaries

I have a document with two different glossaries (using the `glossaries` package), and I would like to use the option `nogroupskip` with one of them but not with the other. I used `\usepackage[nogroupskip]{glossaries}` before, but this obviously acts on both glossaries. I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but this may very well be because I don't know what to search for. Is there a way how I can assign options to one glossary only?

Comment: Well, you could use the `\printglossary` option instead of setting it globally. If you need more help than that hint, please provide an MWE to test against.

Comment: @schtandard Thanks, didn't know you can put that there, sounds like it will do the trick.